# Questions/answers marked as spam

Tags: feature-request, reputation, flags, spam

How can I mark a question or an answer as spam and where can I find the list of Q/A marked as spam? [I had an answer marked as spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43209/lost-reputation-points), and, if I saw the list, I would probably delete it avoiding the penalty of 100 reputation points.

Comment: In this specific case, Maurizio, several people commented on the poor quality of that answer, which you dismissed, somewhat rudely, in later comments.  A later comment, which you might or might not have read, mentioned that the answer was being marked as spam.  I find your comments here somewhat disingenuous.

Comment: @Michael: I don't understand what you mean with: "which you dismissed, somewhat rudely, in later comments". What comments are you referring to?

Comment: @Maurizio, I'm referring to your comment "If you are so frustrated by my answer, ignore it without increase my reputation."

Comment: @Michael: I answered in that manner because I think that the first comment (You've got over 50 reps. You can just leave a comment.) was so rudely too. After doing that, I didn't see that page again and this evening I found my reputation decreased and I asked here what's happened.

Comment: So, to recap, you were aware your answer was unnecessary ("Ok, pheraps a duplicate, but not a spam"), you don't care about it being marked as spam ("And I didn't care about penalties for spam, because my answer was not a spam"), and other users had warned you about the way things were headed ("@Maurizo: you should probably be aware that there is a -100 penalty for spam. This post is at the top of the flagged-as-spam list and is about to reach the number of votes necessary to be penalized.").  You're not putting yourself in the best light here.

Comment: @Michael: I agree with everything you're saying, but remember he almost certainly didn't see the last comment regarding existing flags. (I happened to notice the MSO post as it was happening, he'd have had to been watching for it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43183/what-should-be-done-with-i-agree-with-x-answers)

Comment: @Gnome: you're right about that.  I think what bothers me here is the OP's reluctance to delete what he knew was a poor answer unless there was a penalty to be avoided.

Comment: Pheraps my poor english doesn't help me, or pheraps you like offending people (comments disingenuous, best light, ...). With I didn't care about penalties, I mean that I didn't consider it as a spam. I think that it is better to close here the discussion to avoid boring other people. Bye, have a good evening.

Comment: @Maurizio: Don't take it the wrong way, we're just describing what happened.  You might find the answers on the post I linked to just above useful to see *why* your answer shouldn't have been an answer, or you could ask about it in another meta question if you are still confused.  It's not about taking offense, as such.

Comment: @Gnome: Thank you for your answer and for your link. I didn't read that before. I am happy because there I find some people that thought that my post was not a spam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only see flag votes if you have over 10k reputation.

10k rep users have a list of all questions/answers marked as spam, along with the counts for each.

Comment: The flag-queue no longer exists in the 10K tools so for us mortals we don't see those posts and flags anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a list. Human beans use their judgement to decide when a post is spam. I flag spam when it seems to me that the post is primarily flogging traffic somewhere or pushing a product without either asking or answering a question.