# Why do I lose a lot of points if I tell people to not babble?

Tags: discussion, reputation, specific-question

A question of mine seems to have been removed and I have lost 100 points without any explanation.

I think it's brutal that someone can lose points without explanation while people that make noise are not penalised so significantly.

Comment: Do you have the URL for this question in your browser history?

Comment: Rep != points. (1 more to go).

Comment: Can someone with 10k on SO make us a little summary about it? @eth @gno

Comment: @Downvoter: refresh the page :)

Comment: @giuliocc: FWIW, You did have a little warning and explanation from downvotes and "Suit yourself. You come off as exessively touchy, though, and it'll put people off from helping you. Honey and vinegar and all that. – Michael Petrotta".

Comment: I saw Michael Petrotta's "de-pricklisation" of my question. But I explained the rollback. I wasn't rude or offensive. Just to the point. I think the moderation like this is un-justified the level of power that community based moderators have is somewhat unbalanced.

Unfortunately it appears to be a bit like the wild west.Those with the points can slap anyone around and there are no repercussions as the question was dropped off the radar. No warning nothin....sigh!

Comment: @giuliocc: *Anybody* (with at least 15 rep) can flag a post as "offensive". Enough "offensive" votes, and the post gets deleted automatically. What happened was not the doing of "those with the points". (Personally, I don't agree with the "offensive" votes for your post; it was abrasive but not totally offensive.)

Comment: @greg Hewgill. thanks.. unfortunately, too many "princesses" don't like being told to stay on topic.... definition of offensive seems to include "did you hurt my ego?" as well..ho hum..

Comment: @greg.. Just one other thing. What do i do if a user has been villified for being abrasive but no offensive.. I suppose it's just tough luck ?

Comment: I did try to help...

Comment: @Michael. yep. You did.. but i was voted off the island as it were....

So much for actually trying to control the direction of the responses. Silly me....

Comment: Hahahahahahahahahahahaha! This is hilarious. You are not being serious @giuliocc? This is some social experiment right?

Comment: @Pekka. I didn't start out that way.. But it seems that is has devolved into an experiment. And it has taught me that this place is has royalty.. some princesses about. lol

Comment: Giulio - I don't think this place has that much royalty, just people who expect basic politeness when being asked for free advice.

Comment: I find it strange and mildly amusing that I can tell whether or not a comment was written by guilio just from the text - no confusing the tone or wording or offensive name-calling, I'm guessing - not sure exactly WHAT it is, but it's quite evident. I can only suggest that you find another community if you, Mr. Big Man, don't wanna deal with the prissy princesses that you consider to be so prevalent here.

Comment: @CodeJockey. lol..Glad you find all the plumage I have ruffled entertaining. I have managed to make peace in other forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those interested, [original revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2634868/revisions) below. Michael Petrotta edited to remove the argumentative last sentence along with a few typos, but it was promptly reverted by the OP.

---

## looking for a license key algorithm.

There are alot of questions relating to license keys asked on stackoverflow. But they don't answer this question.

**Can anyone provide a simple license key algorithm that is technology independent and doesn't required a diploma in mathematics to understand ?**

The license key algorithm is similar to public key encryption. I just need something simple that can be implemented in any platform .Net/Java and uses simple data like characters. Preferably no Byte translations required.

So if a person presents a string, a complementary string can be generated that is the authorisation code. Below is a common scenario that it would be used for.

1. Customer downloads s/w which generates a unique key upon initial startup/installation.
2. S/w runs during trial period.
3. At end of trial period an authorisation key is required.
4. Customer goes to designated web-site, enters their code and get authorisation code to enable s/w, after paying :)

Don't be afraid to describe your answer as though you're talking to a 5 yr old as I am not a mathemtician. Just need a decent basic algorithm, we're not launching nukes...

NB: Please no philosophy on encryption nor who is Diffie-Hellman. I just need a basic solution. Stuff that goes off topic will be flagged noise or marked down.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for putting it up again here. I didn't think it was argumentative.. Just strict about getting a solution. I saw noise coming in and wanted to keep it on topic.. But was that "offensive" I don't think so..

Comment: @giu: I find "I just need a basic solution. Stuff that goes off topic will be flagged noise or marked down." offensive as you're assuming I (as an answerer) will do the wrong thing, and it generally indicates that you are unwilling to listen to slightly different views.  You could've stated it better, along with the tone of the much of the rest.  Even if you don't find that part offensive, it's clearly *argumentative* as I said here (almost used "offensive" originally myself).

Comment: Yes point taken.. Have started ettiquette lessons..I have sacked my previous coach, I should have known better. His nickname was the "soup-nazi"

Comment: @gnome. No you missed the point about the mark downs. If you proposed some pseudo code you wouldn't get marked down. If you did what a few respondee's did and tell me that this approach is no good, or i think you can do X and not provide an answer nor reference then that would earn a -1. I was going to mark ppl down if it was just waffle.

But rest assured, that I have seen the error of my ways, and I need to allow waffle and princesses to create noise in order to get someone to propose an actual solution. Such is the law of the cyber jungle.

Comment: @giu: Your new etiquette coach isn't much of an improvement.  Characterization of differing views as "waffling" and those posters as "princesses" doesn't help.

Comment: @gnome.. Sigh! So if you don't answer the question.. and it adds no value then it's.. waffling..

Comment: really? Nota Bene? that is so incredibly pretentious!

Comment: @CodeJockey yeah.. in  hind sight it is pretentious, but what the downvoters weren't seeing, was that other questions in the same topic go absolutely no where towards a meaningful answer. So, I was hoping to "guide" the discussion so that it would be a significant contribution on the forum. So believe it or not, there was a cause for the "greater good" as it were in my mind. But I admit that the autocratic approach to the question totally missed the mark. An old saying comes to mind. Even if you're trying to help the mule, it will still kick you.

Answer (score 15):

> Stuff that goes off topic will be flagged noise or marked down.

That is a threat. Asking a question that ends with a threat is offensive.

The system works!

Comment: well.. once again difference in perceptions. It's not threat. It's advice of a consequence for not sticking to the topic. Perhaps if i also said "will markup concrete answers", would sound less "threatening". But then isn't that the whole point of Stackoverflow ?

Comment: @giuliocc, the whole point of SO is getting good answers, not punishing bad ones.

Comment: @Pavel. I agree that we want to get good answers.. but there is so much "noise", and little ability to filter it out. And anyone who bucks that culture with some frank and honest direction becomes a cyber-pariah... ah well.. let's all put on our tutu's and tiara's... LOL

Comment: @giuliocc, the bar, which is more appropriate place for your rumpus, is at the corner.  Not here.

Answer (score 8):

To add on to json's answer.. I would guess that a few people found [these comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2634868) offensive and flagged the post as such:

> Can anyone provide a simple license key algorithm that is technology independent and doesn't required a diploma in mathematics to understand ?
>
> Don't be afraid to describe your answer as though you're talking to a 5 yr old as I am not a mathemtician. Just need a decent basic algorithm, we're not launching nukes...
>
> NB: Please no philosophy on encryption nor who is Diffie-Hellman. I just need a basic solution. Stuff that goes off topic will be flagged noise or marked down.

This comes back to the old adage that "in order to make friends you must first not make enemies."*

*<sup><sub>I don't know who first said that. I just made it up. So if it eventually becomes a popular aphorism, you heard it here first!</sub></sup>

Comment: yes... very true...

unfortunately, too many "princesses" don't like being told to stay on topic.... definition of offensive seems to include "did you hurt my ego?" as well..ho hum

Answer (score 7):

You announced that you would flag and downvote stuff you don't like:

> Stuff that goes off topic will be flagged noise or marked down.

It seems like people were offended by that, probably especially since you rolled it back after somebody edited it out. The post probably got automatically deleted with a -100 penalty due to six "offensive" flags.

After all, people try to answer your questions out of the goodness of their hearts, and nobody likes to be treated harshly for that.

Comment: well.. I rolled back because all this noise was coming into the responses.. but it's not "offensive" is it ? I think we need a new button next to offensive then called "You hurt my ego and I'm gonna cry now"...LOL...ah well.. i suppose it's tough luck on my part ?

Comment: You mean the button you're pressing right now called **"Complain on meta"**?.

Comment: @JoshK. Hey. that could be another cool button to add as well...thanks..

Answer (score 6):

It was flagged as spam/offensive by 6 users and automatically deleted by the system.

<sub>If that was not the case, and it had exactly 10 upvotes (20 if it was a question), your rep might have been recalced after the deletion of the post by a mod, but this is unlikely.</sub>

Comment: I can't seem to be able to find a dupe that states it directly. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43209/lost-reputation-points. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/how-does-stackoverflow-handle-spam Should be updated, may be. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43231/questions-answers-marked-as-spam mentions the 100 loss.

Comment: Ahh i understand now.. caught by the fine print. I dunno.. I think people need to "man-up". I was to the point about what the responses that were not on topic to the quetsion. Stackoverflow says in it's FAQ. 

".. Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered!.."

Comment: @giuliocc: People did "man up."  That's *precisely* what happened.  They did not appreciate your attitude and expressed their dissatisfaction by flagging your post.  You weren't "to the point", you were rude; if you want to survive on this site, don't downvote and *especially* don't *flag* answers that aren't exactly what you want, and **especially** don't **announce** that you're going to do it, and **especially especially** think carefully before rolling back edits and ignoring warnings from experienced and respected contributors who are trying to help you.

Comment: @aarobot. There is "Man up" and there is also being a little "princess". Looks like I need to get a skirt and tiara then to get on around here.. LOL..

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=man+up

Comment: "Manning up" does not require one to accept abusive tone.  Quite the contrary, I'd think.

Comment: Also, I don't believe you actually did "LOL".

Comment: @giuliocc: Did you just link to urbandictionary from MSO?  Liek OMG WTF this is nutzzzz.  How about instead of *manning up* we talk about *growing up*.

Comment: @Michael. I agree. But at the same time, I thought there was sufficient intestinal fortitude of respondees to understand the question was not intended as a discussion topic, but heck, i just wanted a solution...

I have repented and re-listed the question with honey and spice.

I need to be more tolerant of the "noise", and also know that there are alot of ppl prancing around out there with tiara's to.. LOL

Comment: @Aarobot. That's a great example of being abusive, complete with acronym expletives.. 

I don't believe i have commented with such emotional aggravation nor profanity as you have now.

Comment: @giuliocc: It was mockery of your comment, nothing more, nothing less. It's telling that you expected people to interpret your tone as light-hearted but readily attribute "emotional aggravation" to a 6-word sentence with intentional misspellings.  Besides, the rules are more lax on Meta.

Comment: @aarobot.Mockery of my comments is fine. But profanity is abuse I think...sigh! If you don't like it don't comment...