# Make it clearer that an answer was converted into a comment, not just deleted

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-answers, convert-to-comment

When an answer is converted into a comment, it is marked as "deleted". This can lead to great confusion as to why the answer was deleted, unless the moderator leaves a comment.

Either of these would prevent any confusion:

- Instead of writing "deleted" on the answer, write "converted into a comment."
- Automatically add a comment saying that "Your answer was converted into a comment for [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84402/)."

Comment: I like the 2nd variant, and your proposed text sound good to me.

Comment: I'm more in favor of the second one, probably with some sort of bypass rule like how the "possible duplicate" auto-comment works.

Comment: or the first one could say `converted to a comment on post 123456 by moderatorX ♦`

Comment: We had a user get confused about this: https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301/is-answering-a-question-with-a-question-not-permitted

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The convert to comment moderator function will now display the fact that an answer was converted to a comment after the next build.

EDIT: this is how it will appear

[image]

Comment: Will this be retroactive to previously converted comments?

Comment: @Al - no it won't apply retroactively because we didn't previously have a post history record for this action

Comment: @Geoff: Ah, ok.  Last quick question, is that something that a sub-10k would be able to see?  It was my understanding that answers deleted by someone other than the owner will not be visible to them.

Comment: @Jeff 10ks have always been able to see all deleted posts, regardless of who deleted them

Comment: @Jeff Oh, I completely misread that as 10ks. Ignore me :). So you mean answers deleted by someone other than themselves would not be visible to them

Comment: @michael no, that is not true; deleted answers are always visible to users on the question, if they own the answer.

Comment: When you convert to a comment, you have to pick a location (the question or another answer). Could you add that information to the message?

Comment: Is this supposed to be already active? I just converted [an answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/101102/are-static-classes-with-static-methods-considered-solid/101139#101139) to a comment on a question on Programmers and it still said it was "deleted".

Comment: @GeoffDalgas Has this been implemented? It still doesn't show up on answers converted to a comment...

Comment: I'm not seeing it either. Is it only shown to the person who posted the answer but not to the moderator who converted it?

Comment: Geoff, this apparently shows that note only to the poster himself. 10k-ers and mods still just see `deleted by *`. Can this be extended to all users who can see the deleted post, along with a link to the comment? Should I make a separate feature request?

Comment: It seems to simply be lying about converted to a comment I search the whole page and there was no such comment.