# Consider: Users with 50 reputation in any of the SO sites should be able to comment everyone in all of the SO sites

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges

I use comments to verify things before I try to answer. I can see way one might want to limit new users from commenting: It prevent spam and unrelated comments, although it has disadvantages as it made me post "answers" that should have been comments. After a user has been active enough in a site, I think it's resonable and helpful to give him this privilege in all the sites.

For example, while I have enough reputation to comment on questions on Stack Overflow, I still cannot comment on questions in "Gaming." What's the advantage in that? It just prevents me from helping others.

(Maybe other privileges follow the same logic. For me, commenting is the one I miss the  most.)

Comment: You are new to meta, so if you haven't lurked around a bit, please understand that downvotes here mean that people disagree with the idea, not that the question is bad.

Comment: You now have 200 and get +100 rep in all sites ;)

Comment: @Adam : Thanks for that comment. For a minute there I thought I've done something aweful.

Comment: @Marcelo : Thanks! I wondered why it happened so quickly.

Comment: @all: Thanks. I really didn't knew that. Now I can happily continue

Comment: BTW, is it mentioned anywhere in FAQs / help about reputation?

Comment: Yes: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

Comment: @Gray: I meant if the '+100 rep on other sites when you reach 200 rep' is mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you get 200 points on any *one* Stack Exchange site you will gain a 100 point bonus on *all* sites thus negating the need for this.

So just pick one site and post some good answers. You'll have 200 points in next to no time.

Comment: Wow, timestamps match to the second.  Time for a **CAGE MATCH!!!**

Comment: @Adam the post ids say "you lose, sir" :)

Comment: Thanks - I really didn't knew that. feel a bit stupid now ;)

Comment: @AakashM I demand a recount!

Comment: @j0ker5, BTW, since you do have an account with over 200rep, you can re-associate your accounts on other sites to get the rep bonus for you other accounts.

Comment: @Zoredache - I believe that's automatic now even if you've already set up the association.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you have 200 rep on one account, then every other site you sign up on gets a 100 rep bonus, getting you past all the voting and commenting barriers.

Comment: Oh look! You're now only 2 answer votes away from getting to 200 on stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/users/550269/j0ker5

Comment: I had 166 rep when I posted it... It came to me pretty suddenly :)

Answer (score 1):

From my answer to [Mechanism to Allow New Users to Comment Everywhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94975/mechanism-to-allow-new-users-to-comment-everywhere):

> IMO, you can't really "ask for clarification" correctly as a complete
>   newcomer to the site. Is this question a duplicate? Is this question
>   mis-tagged? Is this a FGITW tag like C# where half the world's
>   population will see it in the next 30 seconds, or is it more a
>   Windows-Error-Reporting kinda thing where you have roughly two weeks,
>   maybe three, before you might be gazumped? While you're typing a
>   comment like "what version of Visual Studio are you using?" have three
>   other people copied-and-pasted their standard "For Visual Studio 2010,
>   do X, and for Visual Studio 2008, do Y" answer? You won't know till
>   you've been here a while. Your only hope is to look for questions that
>   can be answered as they stand. All of us did, somehow.

Still think it's true.