# Please add seconds to determine who answers a question first

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

I am always torn in between 2 similar answers posted at the same minute, and don't know which one to pick. Just to be fair, the person who answers earlier should be picked, but I jsut can't determine because both also answered 5 minutes ago. It's good if I could have 5 minutes 10 seconds ago, and 5 minutes 8 seconds ago. Then I know which to pick.

Comment: I hope you mean just for *accepting* an answer, because if two answers are both good and one is not clearly a copy of the other, you should vote them both up.

Comment: Sometimes it's difficult to determine. Cos the answer is exactly identical.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just hover over the time - the tooltip contains the info you're wanting (this goes for any time we display on the site).

[image]

As an aside, we try to put tooltips on most UI elements, so get those [hover hands](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/hover-hand) going!

Comment: One can also compare the Post ID numbers; [ChrisF](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/consider-users-with-50-reputation-in-any-of-the-so-sites-should-be-able-to-comme/101346#101346) and [Adam Davis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101345/consider-users-with-50-reputation-in-any-of-the-so-sites-should-be-able-to-comme/101347#101347) actually had matching time stamps on answers to a question today.

Answer (score 4):

Ugh, no. You're going at it wrong: you're trying to reward the *best answerer*, you should be rewarding the **best answer**. It's bad enough that earlier answers get an advantage in terms of upvotes, which often leads to them outscoring much better answers that came later. It's impossible to hide the order of answers (without major changes), but the order should not be thrust in your face.  Don't pick the earliest answer, pick the best answer.

Comment: My predicament comes when 2 answers are identical.

Comment: @Victor Look at the post number then. Or toss a coin. The information is there already, but it should not be too visible.

Answer (score 2):

I know that, you want to choose between the quick answerers. But here is a piece of suggestion from my side.

Ideally if they both are good answers and similar then, first you should upvote both of them. Sometimes, getting an upvote, encourages an answerer to illustrate his answer better.

Wait for some more time and let others also answer. In this time, new answers may come or the existing answers may pass from rounds of edits. You can judge a good answer out of it always.

If things remain the same, then you can use the technique mentioned by @Jarrod.