# A solution for commenting without the "Comment Everywhere" privilege

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges

OK, we all know the drill. Low rep users post comments as answers because they don't have the privilege to comment yet. Said answers get flagged NAA and deleted. Rinse and repeat.

Many of these comments are requests for clarification or more information. They're *trying* to get involved, but not yet able to.

The reasons commenting is a privilege and not granted from the beginning are very valid

- We don't like spam. It's especially tricky to police comment spam because comments don't bump the post, and so don't bring eyeballs.
- Low rep users' comments may not be helpful, and add noise while reducing signal.

I propose a solution to low rep commenting that addresses both of these concerns.

#### Solution

Let low rep users comment everywhere, but display their comments *only* to the poster, and allow them to comment *only once* on a post. If the comment gets an upvote, promote it to a real comment. Anyone viewing the comment can flag it, and if necessary even this pseudo-commenting privilege can be revoked.

- The damage by spam in this case is vanishingly small, because it can only reach an audience of one. The only way to circumvent that is by posting many comments. Posting many comments and no answers should warrant an automatic flag, and any spam found lead to account deletion.
- The problem of noise is similarly reduced, as the OP could potentially benefit from the comment, while nobody else need be exposed to it.

Obviously also expose these comments to moderators, and possibly also to 10k users.

> Possible message to user:
> [image]

---

These users *want* to participate. They might even be able to answer this unanswered question if they could only clarify the problem. Or they might have noticed something that could be improved in an answer. They mean well. Let's focus on enabling them to participate in a way that avoids the risk of defacing the site.

Comment: "Anyone viewing the comment can flag it" - this seems to conflict with "display their comments only to the poster".

Comment: This would open the door to possible bullying -> create new account -> post comments on a post hardly anyone will see. An insecure new user receiving this won't know to flag it.

Comment: @Anna, in this case, "anyone" would be the poster, moderators, and possible 10k users

Comment: If only the poster (and moderators) can see these comments, there will be a number of weird-looking one-sided conversations for everyone else to read.

Comment: This takes away one of the motivations to get rep. I am yet to be convinced that the kind of comment or clarifying question that pops into the head of someone who hasn't asked a good question or given a good answer is so precious that we must somehow capture it. Vague questions will always be with us: the users can comment when they have the rep. Wanting to comment may encourage them to do something for the site they wouldn't otherwise do.

Comment: The thing is @kate, they don't. They jump straight to commenting as an answer, making more work for everyone. If they are honestly trying to help, where's the harm?

Comment: I don't have a good solution for you @Martijn. That's a legitimate concern. You could block this feature for commenting on new users' posts, but that seems overly complex. Possibly a message to that user saying `"only you can see this comment. If you feel offended, click the flag"`

Comment: @mhlester: *most* **won't** jump to the answer box. What we see in the review queue are the extremes. *How much of a problem is this really*? I don't think there is *that* much work, and the First Post and Late Answer queues are not backlogged.

Comment: @Martijn, I did it. One of my first answers on SO should have been a comment. I really was trying to be helpful, and the review queues would have just gotten my answer deleted without actually helping the way I'd intended.

Comment: @mhlester: Perhaps you were an exception? And if you revisit that exact same question now, would you have asked the same feedback?

Comment: Yeah, it would have been a useful comment. Just not a complete answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you are suggesting is essentially a private message privilege for people *under* a certain reputation level. We've repeatedly [denied these requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/433/1438) because a PM system is ripe for abuse. Occasionally we get email requests asking to be put in contact with individual users, which we cannot and will not do. Generally the reason people want to contact another user is relatively benign—often people want individual help. It'd be nice if we could find a way to let new users comment, but I think this is not a workable solution.

Remember, comments are ancillary to the main purpose of sites: questions and answers. As frustrating as non-answers as answers are, the current situation is better for new users than one where they are able to participate in non-reputation-earning ways. I'd hate to see some people locked in a comment ghetto when they could be using their time more productively.

Answer (score 6):

This is a bad idea: it violates the principle on Stack Exchange sites that *all communication is public,* with the exception of moderator communication.

It's a good thing communication is public too: it means all of it can be scrutinised, and the bad advice or improper behaviour can be recognised and responded to accordingly.

New users are the ones who tend to misuse comments (even their not-answers are often inappropriate as comments), and so they especially need the scrutiny. I suspect the comment privilege exists at 50 rep so that they're forced to lurk for at least a while and learn how comments are used. Making these comments invisible and giving them a *total lack* of scrutiny is exactly the opposite of what we want!

It can also be absolutely terrible.

> LinuxFan: Your bash script is using its booleans wrong. Bash uses inverse booleans where 0 is true and 1 is false - [read more about it here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933843/) You need to rethink your boolean logic.

> Newbie: You can just change it back to regular boolean mode with the command `rm rf /`

> TotallyOblivious: That's a good recommendation. Let us know how it goes OP.

> OP: Help! I'm posting from my laptop, my PC isn't working now!

> LinuxFan: What? What'd you do?

Hover over the spoiler to see the one comment the OP sees and *nobody else does* except for moderators.

It likely won't be that bad, but c'mon, communication being public is important.

Comment: This is essentially a more fleshed out version of Martijn Pieters comment, with a more contrived (though funny) example. Showing the poster that this comment isn't visible to anyone else would still help mitigate it.

Comment: But we can all agree comments are valuable; that's why we have them. Funny enough, [another post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214148/allow-comments-for-all-users-create-comments-review-queue) about allowing comments from all users was bumped between my question and your answer. There's definitely a desire from them to be able to participate more.

Comment: Sure, I have no problem with new users being able to comment. Comments being invisible, though, would be bad.

Comment: ... it should be `rm -rf /` instead of `rm rf /`, you missed a `-` ...