# Why do you not allow comments until certain reputation is acquired on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, comments

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment)
>   [Lower commenting threshold to 1 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/lower-commenting-threshold-to-1-rep)

I would really like to ask somebody a question through the comment system, but my reputation on Stack Overflow is 19. I'm pretty sure I can answer the question, but I want to ask him something specific. I don't want to answer the question with a question.

So why do they not allow comments until a higher reputation is achieved?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment), [Lower commenting threshold to 1 rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/lower-commenting-threshold-to-1-rep)

Answer (score 2):

When you comment, the activity would not show up on the main page. If there was no rep cap, spammers could have used this and posted all their spam over Stack Overflow, and take some time before the users have been noticed. You can comment on your own posts, though.

If you want to comment, post more high-quality answers/questions and gain more rep.