# Why is such high reputation needed for the comments-everywhere privilege?

Tags: discussion, comments, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [50 reputation for making comments is too high](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53647/50-reputation-for-making-comments-is-too-high)

I've joined stack overflow fairly recently, and although I haven't got a chance
to give an answer that others haven't give (Though I haven't gone out of my way to find questions).

On several occasions, I've had constructive input that doesn't warrant an answer but
would be useful as a comment.

What is the reason for such a high reputation requirement?

Comment: 50 points is not exactly high. It's easily earned with a few well-placed answers. Or even *one* good answer, if it comes to that.

Comment: 50 points can be earned by 25 accepted [meta-tag:suggested-edits]

Comment: You could always help the community(and receive reputation in exchange) by providing valid edits to posts an answers.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71368/lower-commenting-threshold-to-1-rep?rq=1

Comment: @Luksprog Ok, I didn't know about suggested edits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the ability to earn 50 reputation, you can comment.

This is just to prevent spam and unwanted comments from inexperienced users.

Answer (score 2):

50 rep is high reputation its fairly enough imho. It is to prevent spam.

One or two good  answer will get you the needed upvotes.