# Allow new users 1 comment?

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users

I don't know if it's a problem on all sites, but on [Genealogy & Family History SE](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com) I see that often new users just want to add a comment, but they can't because there is a 50 rep requirement. So they post an answer instead. Then this answer is flagged. Then a mod converts the answer to a comment. Then we never see the user again.

An example just now is this post: https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/11880/1107

It's a very useful comment, but it's a comment on the answer above, not an answer.

Now I understand that there are very good reasons for the 50 reputation requirement for comments and I did notice the post [Allow new users to comment for X times in a day](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207528/allow-new-users-to-comment-for-x-times-in-a-day)  but I wonder if there can/should be any accommodations.

An option might be to allow users to make only 1 comment if they have less than 50 rep, and no more comments allowed until they achieve 50 rep.

It's not a perfect solution, far from it. I'm just trying to think of ways to stop this from happening because I feel like a lot of new users are lost because of the fact that they can't comment, or comment incorrectly. On beta sites trying to grow, it's important to do everything we can to retain new users.

Comment: So we let them make one comment, and then someone responds to theirs, and they're not allowed to reply to that if it requests additional information? Or users would just be incredibly confused by the "I need 50 reputation? But I already posted one." This sounds like it'd lead to an even worse user experience than just not allowing them to comment. If they still can't comment after the first one, they'll just go back to the normal habits we're trying to prevent with this feature.

Comment: @animuson I did say it wasn't a perfect solution. :D It would of course require a clear alert message when the user commented the first time, or tried to comment again, explaining that 50 rep is required in order to make further comments. Even if they can't make any more replies at that point, I think having first comments in the proper place would be a positive step.

Comment: They could then create many different accounts and comment unlimitedly.

Comment: See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment

Comment: @John Good point, but the same thing could be done with answers/questions, and there are (I believe) mechanisms in place to prevent this

Comment: If they delete their first comment can they now reuse it to post a new one?

Comment: @random My assumption, were this implemented, would be no

Comment: Just as an aside – the comment I linked to above has now been downvoted (even though it was a perfectly useful contribution), converted to a comment, and is now sitting in the wrong place as a comment to the question rather than a comment to the answer. There is no explanation to the new user what has just happened. It could be so easy to have the comment in the right place to start with.

Comment: You can't downvote a comment. That comment could also have been fleshed out to an answer, or a suggested edit

Comment: @random I (obviously) meant the answer that was actually a comment was downvoted. Additionally, the comment was in response to another comment on the answer, and should definitely not have been fleshed out as an answer, because it was not in any way an answer to the question. It also could not be a suggested edit, because it was in no way an edit to the answer. It was a comment, put in the answer box because the user could not add a comment.

Comment: Should be reopened, related, but definitely not a duplicate.

Comment: @HarryVervet - If the answer is actually a comment then it actually isn't helpful.  **An answer cannot be both a comment and an answer.**

Comment: @Ramhound Exactly, it isn't an answer. I'll repeat: It was a helpful comment, put in the answer box because the user could not make a comment.

Comment: Comments submitted as answers are not helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound If you want to make this an argument over semantics: It was a **helpful comment**, which had to be put in the answer box. It's not helpful that the new user had no other place he could put it.

Comment: I agree with @John that one comment total before reaching 50 rep is different to X comments per day before reaching 50.  I think what HarryVervet is suggesting would let us know that we have someone taking their first nibble at the site which gives us an opportunity to try and hook them by welcoming them and explaining how to get 50 rep to comment everywhere.

Comment: If I'm allowed to chip in, I have also noticed that new, unregistered, users will edit an old question, or answer and post *their* comment / solution / observation / useful contribution  within the actual post. Very often this means the suggested edit will be rejected, and that useful comment lost forever. For clarity's sake, I'm not talking about trollish behaviour.

Comment: Why not post an "answer", (or should that be a comment?) on the older question? EDIT: Damn, just noticed this question was asked in **July**.