# How to handle user posting a question as answer since the user can't comment

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, answers, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to deal with 1-rep users who answer but should comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55708/how-to-deal-with-1-rep-users-who-answer-but-should-comment)

How to handle user posting a question as answer ?.I downvoted and now the user is complaining that he hasn't got 50 points to comment and I'm not letting him to gain the points needed to comment by downvoting.How to handle this situation? The mentioned post is posted below

[Other ItemsSource in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6122279/other-itemssource-in-wpf/6122492#6122492)

**UPDATE**

I flagged the comment and the mods have already converted the answer to a comment.Still like to discuss over the matter.Is this limitation necessary..? Its forcing users to create comments as answers and creating more work for the mods

Comment: You should flag it as not an answer and leave them a comment telling them that it's not an answer.  There are plenty of questions that answers can at least be started on, without needing to get extra information from the OP.  I don't see anything wrong with asking for additional information in your answer, if the answer at least has some useful content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to deal with 1-rep users who answer but should comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55708/how-to-deal-with-1-rep-users-who-answer-but-should-comment), [Lower the amount of reputation needed to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12119/lower-the-amount-of-reputation-needed-to-comment), [Remove reputation minimum to comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51408/remove-reputation-minimum-to-comment)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would flag it for moderator attention and get them to convert the answer to a comment.  You could also comment on the answer to let the OP, and other users, what you have done.

Comment: I did downvote and also flagged the comment

Comment: @biju: I don't think there is much point in down voting as the down vote will become void after the answer has been converted to a comment anyway.